# Docker Compose: Remap a containers port to be the same inside the network and on the host

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two dockerized applications that are part of a docker network and which both start on the 8080 port. I need them both to be exposed on the host machine, that's why I expose them to 8080 and 8081 correspondingly.

```
app-1:
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"

app-2:
  ports:
    - "8081:8080"
```

I don't have control over these applications (I cannot change their ports), they are only a part of an end-to-end test suite that needs to be run in order to execute tests.

**Problem:** Depending on wether I execute tests in a docker container (a 3d application in the same docker-compose file) or locally, I have to use different ports (8080 or 8081) because the requests go either within a docker network or over the host machine. It is inconvenient.

**Question:** Is there a way to remap ports in the compose file the way that the port will be the same inside and outside the docker network? For instance, it would be great if I could refer to `app-2` using the 8081 port *inside* the docker network.

I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Can't you make the program listen on another port?

Comment: @SuperSandro2000 if I could it wouldn't be an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and I resolved it using the following method. It was a NodeJS-express application.

1. I ran a container on the defined port and connected with the CLI of
   the container. Found the Environment file in which the port was
   defined.
2. Copied that file using `docker cp` onto my local machine.
3. Modified the file and updated the port.
4. Stopped the Container.
5. Replaced the environment file inside the container with the updated
   file again

using `docker cp`

Committed that container as an image using `docker commit`

Ran the container on the updated port and using the newly committed image.

Comment: Well, this requires manual efforts, just like manually changing port in my current approach. This is something I want to avoid.

Comment: There is no other way to do it as you can only map the port on which your application is listening. This requires manual effort once as you can commit the image and then use it instead of the provided one. One other way can be to volume map the env file with the updated port.